# Can women do job in islam

Tags: sharia

My question is that can women do jobs in Islam if they do not had any income source if they have any problem in their home

Answer (score 0):

Yes, women are allowed to work outside the home, as the Quran and the Sunnah do not forbid women from working and earning income, especially when she has to work to meet the financial needs of the family.

There are certain conditions that apply though:

1. The job itself must not involve anything that is forbidden in Islam (e.g. serving alcohol); likewise it must not prevent her from fulfilling her Islamic duties (e.g. performing daily prayers, observing hijab). This condition of course applies to both men and women.
2. A woman needs to obtain consent from her husband (if married) or from her father/wali (if not married).
3. Islam does teach that a woman's primary responsibility is **looking
   after the home** and making sure the home is running well; so a
   working woman should make sure that her work isn't causing her to neglect her duties at home.

In most cases, especially in families with small children, the best course of action is for the wife to stay at home and for the husband to work; but every family situation is different, so each family has to do their own cost-benefit analysis, depending on their own particular circumstances.